# dispatchEvent error in storyboard

Tags: lua, coronasdk

When i pressed the credits button from the menu it gave me an error  "?:0: attempt to call method 'dispatchEvent' (a nil value) ?:in function 'gotoScene'...scene_menu.lua:35: in function ...scene_menu.lua:33>?:in function "...Whats the problem here?

This is my menu page

```
-- scene_menu.lua

local storyboard = require( "storyboard" )
local scene = storyboard.newScene()

-- Clear previous scene
storyboard.removeAll()

--forward references
local background
local title
local playGame
local tutorial 
local credits


display.setStatusBar(display.HiddenStatusBar)



function playgameBtn( event )
  transition.to(playGame, {time = 1000, alpha = 0, xScale = 2, yScale = .6})
  storyboard.gotoScene("playgame", "fade", 1000)
end

function tutorialBtn (event)
  transition.to(tutorial, {time = 1000, alpha = 0, xScale = 2, yScale = .6})
  storyboard.gotoScene("tutorial", "fade", 1000)
 end

 function creditsBtn (event)
  transition.to(credits, {time = 1000, alpha = 0, xScale = 2, yScale = .6})
  storyboard.gotoScene("credits", "fade", 1000)
 end

 function scene:createScene(event)
 local group = self.view

 background = display.newImage( "bkg_clouds.png")
 group:insert(background)
 background.x = 240
 background.y = 195


 title = display.newText("Shoot the Balloons!", 250, 100, native.systemFont, 25 )
 title:setFillColor( 1,1, 0 )


 playgame = display.newImage("Play Button.png")
 group:insert(playgame)
 playgame.x = 250
 playgame.y = 150

 tutorial = display.newImage("Tutorial Button.png")
 group:insert(tutorial)
 tutorial.x = 250
 tutorial.y = 200

 credits = display.newImage("Credits Button.png")
 group:insert(credits)
 credits.x = 250
 credits.y = 250
 end

function scene:enterScene( event )
    playgame:addEventListener("tap", playgameBtn)
    tutorial:addEventListener("tap", tutorialBtn)
    credits:addEventListener("tap", creditsBtn)
  end

function scene:exitScene(event)
playgame:removeEventListener("tap", playgameBtn)
tutorial:removeEventListener("tap", tutorialBtn)
credits:removeEventListener("tap", creditsBtn)
end

function scene:destroyScene(event)

end

scene:addEventListener("createScene", scene)
scene:addEventListener("enterScene", scene)
scene:addEventListener("exitScene", scene)
scene:addEventListener("destroyScene", scene)

return scene
```

This is my main.lua

```
-- main.lua
display.setStatusBar( display.HiddenStatusBar )                 
local storyboard = require "storyboard"                               
storyboard.gotoScene( "scene_splash" )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change the name credits.lua to the other name or change the variable name credits global variable,i think its due to the conflict of name in this line:`storyboard.gotoScene("credits", "fade", 1000)`

Comment: I don't think this is the issue.  Since the "credits" in the gotoScene is a string and is not passing the variable.

Comment: I changed the file name credits.lua to scene_credits and it worked. :) thank you!